# How to use onmousehover event on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function show_function() {
                var example_image=document.getElementById("example_image");
                example_image.src="example_one.png";
            }
            function hide_function() {
                var example_image=document.getElementById("example_image");
                example_image.src="example.png";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="one" onmouseover="show_function()" onmouseout="hide_function()">
        <img id="example_image" src="example.png">
    </div>
    <div class="two" onmouseover="show_function()" onmouseout="hide_function()">
        <img id="example_image" src="example.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hover the mouse over first div,the image changes. But when I hover the mouse over second div then also the image from the first div changes.

Does anyone know how to do it only in javascript?

Comment: Pass `this` as the argument?

Comment: pass "this" as function parameter, then use it inside your function, to target the element/adjacent elements you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Danko said, ID must be unique. Next step will be to insert variables into your function:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function show_function(id, hide)
{
    var example_image=document.getElementById(id);

    if(hide){
    example_image.src="example.png";
    } else{
    example_image.src="example_one.png";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one" 
onmouseover="show_function('example_image1')" 
onmouseout="show_function('example_image1', true)" />
<img id="example_image1" src="example.png">
</div>
<div class="one" 
onmouseover="show_function('example_image2')" 
onmouseout="show_function('example_image2', true)" />
<img id="example_image2" src="example.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or you can go like this too:

```
<img src="example.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='example_one.png';" 
onmouseout="this.src='example.png';" />
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
show_function = function (container) {
    container.childNodes[1].src = "example_one.png";
}
hide_function = function (container) {
    container.childNodes[1].src = "example.png";
}
```

then in HTML, pass `this` to function:

```
<div class="one" onmouseover="show_function(this)" onmouseout="hide_function(this)">
    <img id="example_image" src="example.png">
</div>
<div class="two" onmouseover="show_function(this)" onmouseout="hide_function(this)">
    <img id="example_image" src="example.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the first child node [0] of the div. and pass the hovered object into the callback.

```js
function show(e){ 
  document.getElementById('label').innerHTML = e.children[0].id;
  e.style.border = "solid 2px red";
  } 

function hide(e){ 
  
  e.style.border = "0";
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="one" onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide(this)">
<img id="example_image" src="example.png" class="one" >
</div>
<div class="two" onmouseover="show(this)" onmouseout="hide(this)">
<img id="example_image" src="example.png" class="two">
</div>
<p id='label' ></p>
```